# runas argument savecred and netonly are incompatible?

Tags: winforms, batch-file, command-line-arguments, runas, dsa

i wrote this:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME /savecred "mmc dsa.msc"
```

but with /netonly the argument /savecred don't work

Someone help me?

Comment: If you are going to save the credentials, better use `cmdkey`

Answer (score -2):

/netonly is compatible with /savecred, this is not your problem. What exactly happens ? What error do you have ? And also why do you want to use /netonly ? Is it because you want to start mmc on a remote computer ?

Comment: i need to start dsa with a network user, without netonly batch show error 740 The requested operation requires elevation.With netonly and savecred nothing happens, with netonly work, but i have insert password every time